# how we can increase size of StringBuffer?

Tags: java, stringbuffer

I want to set size of my StringBuffer object as per requirement in code.

```
 StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

 for (List<Integer> l : lists)
 {
   sb.delete(0, sb.length());
   //here i want to set size of sb according to l.size()
 }
```

I want to set size different on each iteration.

Comment: Hint: try reading the Javadoc that comes with classes like http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html . Of course, it is nice for people answering your question to pimp their reputation; but besides that there is really no benefit to the community by asking something that trivial.In addition: consider using a StringBuilder instead of StringBuffer.

Comment: I know that it is trivial type question but it has good thing to know how it is possible to do this. Because there no any method in StringBuffer class itself.

Comment: Well, what are you expecting? A StringBuffer can be created with a given capacity; and the javadoc tells you: "ah, right, the capacity can not be changed later on". Now what kind of answer do you expect when asking for "how can I change the capacity?" ... other people can't magically add such methods to the class. Besides: why are you worried about the capacity at all? Are you dealing with millions of list elements; and the need to micro-optimize your code therefore?

Answer (score 1):

If you want your `StringBuffer` to be initialized with the size of your `List`, just initialize it by passing the size as `int`:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(l.size());
```

**Edit**

If you need to set your size dynamically, based on the values in your `List`, you can use the following idiom:

```
List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1,2,3}));
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
for (int i: l) {
    sb.setLength(i);
}
```

**Side-note**

You don't need to use `StringBuffer` unless you are mutating it in a multi-threaded context.

You could use `StringBuilder` instead.

Comment: StringBuilder  is also same not have any option to increase size

Comment: if we call this method then it will add blank spaces in buffer and if we append other string then that string will be added after that space.

Comment: same is with StringBuilder, that class is not having any specific method to define size.

Comment: @VinaySharma the "specific method to define size" **is** `setLength`. Not sure it does what you want it to - [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#setLength%28int%29)'s the link to the API. Not really sure what you want it do to on the other hand...

Comment: @Mena `setLength` does not change the capacity of the buffer.

Comment: @sudocode looks that it does impact on the capacity from a quick look at the source - see invocation of `ensureCapacityImpl`. Again, the question seems to have some ambiguity here, so I'm not sure I understand the latest version of OP's problem.